Drawing Feynman Diagrams in Microsoft Visio
I am working on my MSc thesis on Quantum Electrodynamics. I have to draw some Feynman diagrams for Compton scattering and similar processes, for which I want to use Microsoft Visio. I am having a hard time figuring out how to draw the photon lines (a wavy line) in Visio. Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated. Please note that I am not trying to promote Microsoft products.
